# Match IPv4 and IPv6 addresses but NOT hostname?

Tags: java, ipv6, ipv4

I want to check if a string is an IPv4 or IPv6 address, but NOTHING else. Is there any way to accomplish this using standard java libs?

I know of:

- InetAddress.getByName(str) - but it accepts hostnames
- IPAddressUtil.isIPv4LiteralAddress(str) - but it is an internal class and will give compiler warnings

I know I could use regular expressions, but I prefer to use existing methods.

Comment: I think we can agree that there is no standard (as in, included by default) way of accomplishing this. What I ended up doing was to run the supposed IP address through a sloppy IPv4|6 regexp (to sort out anything that does not _look_ like a valid IP address) and then call InetAddress.getByName(str) on the address.

Comment: could you post the working solution in java ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use InetAddresses.forString(), from this library:

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.java

Comment: That looks like a really nice class.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this in C is to use [inet_pton()](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/curl/curl-42/curl/lib/inet_pton.c). You could port the code to Java. (Or use some really complicated regular expressions, because matching IPv6 addresses isn't simple.)

You could take a look at the regular expression in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208814) and change it so it doesn't match hostnames, if you're feeling brave. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) supports both IPv4 and IPv6 in a polymorphic manner.  It has methods to do what you are describing.

Here is [sample code](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/#_Toc456708505) that solves your problem.

Here is more sample code:

```
IPAddressString ipString = new IPAddressString("ipv4 or ipv6 address string goes here");
System.out.println("IPv4: " + ipString.isIpV4() + " IPv6: " + ipString.isIpV6());
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple rule of thumbs is if the address is x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x then its an IPV6 address...Try looking into the classes Inet4Address and Inet6Address as well.

Comment: Sure, but then there's short forms (skipping zeroes), loopback address, etc.