# Simple Java regex to extract IP address and port from enclosing string

Tags: java, regex, port, extract, ip-address

Consider a pair of `IPv4` or `IPv6` address and port, separated by either `/` or `:`, e.g.

```
10.10.10.10:1234
```

The port is optional, so strings like

```
10.10.10.10/
10.10.10.10:
10.10.10.10
```

are also valid. The address/port pair may be followed by space or comma characters and it is part of a much longer enclosing string.

What would be a very simple regex to extract the 2 values in separate fields from the enclosing string (without using String manipulation functions)?

For example, an expression like

```
(?<address>[^\s,]+[^\s,:\.])((/|:)(?<port>\d*))?
```

extracts both address and port in the same string.

The goal here is to achieve extraction with the simplest possible regex, even if it is not 100% accurate (i.e., even if it matches other strings as well).

Comment: If it's not a problem if it is simple *and long*, check this (no port but can be appended) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483855/javascript-regex-to-validate-ipv4-and-ipv6-address-no-hostnames

Comment: Why a regex? Regular `String` methods are better here

Comment: I have seen many such regular expressions, but looking for a simple one. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([0-9.]*)(\/|:)([0-9]*)
```

Here is the regex . First group gives you IP.  Third group gives you the Port number. Middle group gives separator i.e / or : used for alternation. It can be ignored.

Comment: It works fine for IPv4 but does not cover IPv6. Thanks and +1.

Comment: could you give me a sample for IPv6 address ?

Comment: IPV6 addresses contain numbers [0-9], letters [A-F] and : symbols, e.g. `1234:ab8:46a3::2a8e:567:1234` is an IPv6 address.

Comment: okay. is the number of colons : fixed before the port number colon ?i.e 4 ?

Comment: No, it can be any number, from 0 to quite a few and you can never know how many exactly.

Comment: so the last : automatically acts as the separator for the port number

Comment: Yes, if it is used as such, because the separator for the port may as well be `/`. But, for sure, the IP address ends only with a number or letter, not `:` or `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [commons validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/):

```
InetAddressValidator validator = InetAddressValidator.getInstance();
if (validator.isValid(ipAddress) {
   // cool, isn't valid
}
throw new InvalidAddressException(ipAddress);
```

Comment: Regular expressions are not the way to go here, PNS.

Comment: They are the only way. The address/port pair is extracted from a long string, as I say in the question, and that long string also has other fields that nee to be extracted. So, the regular expression I asked for will be part of a much longer one.