# find IP address and port in a text file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file which have text similar to mentioned below

> harry's source ip and port combination is 192.168.4.1/5897 and he is
>   trying to access destination 202.158.14.1/7852

The text may vary. My task is to find the first pair of IP and port.

However my code is not working

```
import re

with open('traffic.txt', 'r') as file:
    fi = file.readlines()
re_ip = re.compile("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
re_port = re.compile("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$\/(\d+)")

for line in fi:
    ip = re.findall(re_ip,line)
    port = re.findall(re_port,line)
    print port , ip
```

Comment: "my code is not working" - include the complete error message.

Comment: consider `import ipaddress` in python 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Java regex to extract IP address and port from enclosing string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757311/simple-java-regex-to-extract-ip-address-and-port-from-enclosing-string). The answer is for Java, but the regex is the same in both languages.

Comment: Hint: What hurts you is `"^"` and `"$"`.

Comment: Thanks DYZ , without ^ and $ it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Correct code

```
import re

with open('traffic.txt', 'r') as file:
    fi = file.readlines()


re_ip = re.compile("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")
re_port = re.compile("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/(\d+)")

for line in fi:
    port = re.findall(re_port,line)
    ip = re.findall(re_ip,line)
    print "PORT is  " , port , "ip is " ,ip
```

Comment: I feel '/' needs to be replaced with ':' in re_port. 
 `re_port = re.compile("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:(\d+)")`