# Powershell script to check IPv4 and IPv6 pattern recursively in the entire drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, ipv6, ipv4, powershell-4.0

I want to extract IPv4 and IPv6 pattern wherever used in the bunch of files/codes. I am using the below script but that fetches me only IPv4.

```
$regex = "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b"
cd "D:\"
$excluded = @("*.pdf", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.dll", "*.exe", "*.gif", "*.png", "*.css", "*.vbproj", "*.vspscc", "*.rpt", "*.pdb", "*.zip", "*.rar", "*.flv", "*.cache", "*.dat", "*.bin", "*.sln", "*.wmv", "*.mpg", "*.mpeg", "*.tif", "*.ppt", "*.pptx" ,"*.pps", "*.pub", "*.swf", "*.msi")
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -exclude $excluded | 
Select-String -Pattern $regex | Select-Object path,line,linenumber,filename | Export-Csv -Path "D:\result.csv" -notype
```

How can I fetch all the possible patterns of IPv6 addresses along with IPv4, recursively. I am using Powershell 2.0

Comment: Create another regex that matches IPv6 and add it to the regex?

Comment: [Matching IPv6 addresses - REGEX](http://www.regextester.com/25)

Comment: its not working...its extracting lines as  `<xsl:if test="(1=position()) or (preceding-sibling::*[1]/@Project != @Project)">`

Comment: What I meant was that you can combine two regex strings using the `|` operator. (e.g. `(REGEX1)|(REGEX2)`)

Comment: First I tried using the IPv6 regular expression in the link you mentioned. Just to check if that works but that did not work. And why do I need to combine both?

Comment: Have fun : http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/296am/3/

Comment: You would combine them to match **both** IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: @SamuelAllan I combined but still extracting unwanted lines.

Comment: @SamuelAllan I combined and it is extracting both IPv4 and IPv6 but it is also selecting lines as `<xsl:if test="(1=position()) or (preceding-sibling::*[1]/@Source != @Source)">`. The problem is I have almost a million files to search so I can get more lines like that which will be difficult to filter.

Comment: Ahh I get you now, I'll look in to it. I think there was a way to filter them out in powershell, not that I remember it off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$|^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$|^\s*((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2})|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,4})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(:(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:)))(%.+)?*$
```

I hope this helps. From : [Javascript regex to validate IPv4 and IPv6 address, no hostnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483855/javascript-regex-to-validate-ipv4-and-ipv6-address-no-hostnames)

Example of PowerShell use :

```
"0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001" -match "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$|^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$|^\s*((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2})|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,4})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(:(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:)))(%.+)?$"
```

Comment: Will it work with Powershell? I just tried and it did not work for me. I am just replacing `$regex` in my script with this reg exp.

Comment: Updated answer (removed useless `\s*`)

Comment: I am setting reg exp you mentioned in the `$regex` and no other change in the script. It is selecting IPv6 patters but along with it is selecting other statements like `div.HPLevel1Style`. Pls tell me, if I am wrong somewhere.