# adressHow to add empty value detection to an existing regular expression in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have this regular expression, to validate Ipv4 and Ipv6 address

```
ng-pattern='/^(?=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)(?:(?:25[0-5]|[12][0-4][0-9]|1[5-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.?){4}$|(?=^(?:[0-9a-f]{0,4}:){2,7}[0-9a-f]{0,4}$)(?![^:]*::.+::[^:]*$)(?:(?=.*::.*)|(?=\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+))(?:(?:^|:)(?:[0-9a-f]{4}|[1-9a-f][0-9a-f]{0,3})){0,8}(?:::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}(?:$|:)){0,6})?$/'
```

But If I leave my field empty, the pattern validates the text.

I need to add in this regex the fact that the field musn't be empty.

Thanks

Comment: maybe have a lookie here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483855/javascript-regex-to-validate-ipv4-and-ipv6-address-no-hostnames

Comment: I didn't find an answer to my question. My regex for ipv4 and ipv6 is working, but I need to add the fact that the field cannot be empty in this regex.

Comment: Add `(?=.)` after `^`. Also, perhaps, add `ng-trim="false"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `required` attribute to the `<input>` element:

```
<form name="form1">
  <input ng-model="data" name="input1" required
         ng-pattern='/^(?=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)(?:(?:25[0-5]|[12][0-4][0-9]|1[5-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.?){4}$|(?=^(?:[0-9a-f]{0,4}:){2,7}[0-9a-f]{0,4}$)(?![^:]*::.+::[^:]*$)(?:(?=.*::.*)|(?=\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+))(?:(?:^|:)(?:[0-9a-f]{4}|[1-9a-f][0-9a-f]{0,3})){0,8}(?:::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}(?:$|:)){0,6})?$/'
  />
</form>
```

The ["required" validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) will check if the input is empty.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/WV9eyXdqawzkHw2Of9C3?p=preview)

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app>
    <form name="form1">
      <input ng-model="data" name="input1" required
             ng-pattern='/^(?=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)(?:(?:25[0-5]|[12][0-4][0-9]|1[5-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.?){4}$|(?=^(?:[0-9a-f]{0,4}:){2,7}[0-9a-f]{0,4}$)(?![^:]*::.+::[^:]*$)(?:(?=.*::.*)|(?=\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+:\w+))(?:(?:^|:)(?:[0-9a-f]{4}|[1-9a-f][0-9a-f]{0,3})){0,8}(?:::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}(?:$|:)){0,6})?$/'
      />
    </form>
    <br>
    {{data}}
    <br>
    Form1 input1 valid - {{form1.input1.$valid}}
    <div ng-show="form1.$invalid">
    ERROR: {{form1.input1.$error}}
    </div>
    
  </body>
```