# How to validate IPv4 and IPv6 with PHP

Tags: php

Note! I can not use filter_var in my application. Only generic functions.
Perhaps a regex?

```
<?php
  if (is_valid_ipv4($ip)) { ... }
  else if (is_valid_ipv6($ip) { ... }
  else { ... }
?>
```

Comment: Look into [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and the [`FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "generic functions"?

Comment: Why not filter_var()? It's core PHP, difficult to get more generic than that

Comment: A regex could be like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483855/javascript-regex-to-validate-ipv4-and-ipv6-address-no-hostnames

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Please try reading the question.

Comment: @MarkBaker Unfortunately, in the environment where I work this function is disabled. Don't ask why.

Comment: I spent as much time reading your question as you did researching your problem. Googling "validate ipv4 with regex" and "validate ipv6 with regex" returns several results so since you make no mention of trying anything at all, don't expect top-notch effort from people coming across your post.

Comment: Anyways, check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/53497/2191572

Answer (score 8):

You can just use [inet_pton](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php). It returns false if the IP is not a valid IPv6 or IPv4:

```
function validateIP($ip){
    return inet_pton($ip) !== false;
}
```

Comment: plus 1 for teaching me something new

Comment: Careful, though: `inet_pton()` also throws `E_WARNING` along with returning `false` if the supplied value is not valid

Comment: @ishegg I was just about to comment the same thing about `E_WARNING` but I think that returning `false` is not totally unexpected for PHP.

Comment: Certainly an interesting option, but the question then is, what is the complexity / performance of the underlying code of this function vs `filter_var()`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus [the lastest PHP7 alpha (7.3.0alpha1)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/NEWS) suppresses the warning (just now found out when researching this)

Comment: @ishegg Interesting. Unfortunately people are still rocking PHP 5.x like it's 2005 still so I think suppressing it with `@inet_pton()` would be a useful option.