# Regex to determine if IPv6 or IPv4 and if port is given - working in www.regexr.com but not in my Javascript file

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
var regexForAddress = /^(?:[0-9.]+|(?:\[[0-9a-fA-F:]+\]))$/;
var address = String('[2a00:1397:4:2a02::a1]:50434').match(regexForAddress);
console.log("Reached user customer data for user PublicIp address is " + address);
```

Ok I have IPV6 as this '[2a00:1397:4:2a02::a1]:50434' and 127.0.0.1:50434. Would like to get the IP addresses without the port for IPV6 and IPV4. Thank you.
showing null in the address of console.log of JS but working in [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/3hpvt). Kindly help me in this regard.

[image]

Comment: That isn't the same test string in your example and your screenshot? Please give the regexer.com link in your post.

Comment: https://regexr.com/3hpvt.

Comment: Have you seen any of the related threads on this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483855/javascript-regex-to-validate-ipv4-and-ipv6-address-no-hostnames

Comment: @KrishnaRangampally That's not the same regular expression.

Comment: Ok I have IPV6 as this '[2a00:1397:4:2a02::a1]:50434'. Would like to get the IP address without the port. Thank you

Comment: @KrishnaRangampally I edited the link into the question for you, but you should really edit that and the info you just gave *into the question itself* rather than just posting it down here in the comments. There's an edit option right below the question tags.

Comment: Your code works "fine" if you use the same regex from your regexr.com link:  https://jsfiddle.net/eakt12hz/     It's not working because it's not the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `$`, since it won't match when the address is followed by `:port`.

```js
var regexForAddress = /^(?:[0-9.]+|\[[0-9a-fA-F:]+\])/;
console.log('127.0.0.1:50434'.match(regexForAddress));
console.log('[2a00:1397:4:2a02::a1]:50434'.match(regexForAddress));
```

If you only want to match when there's a port after the address, use a lookahead to require the port but not include it in the match. You can put `$` in the lookahead.

```js
var regexForAddress = /^(?:[0-9.]+|\[[0-9a-fA-F:]+\])(?=:\d+$)/;
console.log('127.0.0.1:50434'.match(regexForAddress));
console.log('[2a00:1397:4:2a02::a1]:50434'.match(regexForAddress));
```

Comment: Sorry if I have one more test case of hostname like localhost:50434. Could you let me know the regex for that please. Thank you

Comment: Add `localhost` as an other alternative in the first group.

Comment: `(?:[0-9.]+|\[[0-9a-fA-F:]+\]|localhost)`

Comment: Sorry it could be any hostname like mydomain.com:50434 or en.wikipedia.org:50434.

Comment: Then replace `localhost` with a regexp for hostnames. `[\w.-]+`

Comment: Could you kindly let me know for the test case: [2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1/64]:50434, is not working. Thank you

Comment: Because the regexp doesn't allow `/` characters.

Comment: That's a subnet address, not the address of a specific host.

Comment: Could you kindly look into this regex as it has that test case working, but not in JS code. Thank you
https://regexr.com/3hpvt

Comment: That has two capture groups, so the return value of `.match()` will be an array with two elements. Is that what you expect? And why do you put a non-capture group inside a capture group? `((?::))`

Comment: I was looking at this stackoverflow and combined all three IPV6 and IPv4 and hostnames to work for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208814/validate-ipv4-ipv6-and-hostname