# python 2.7 grab IPs from Source code

Tags: python, html, parsing, ip

I've already googled my question but i havent any solution at the moment. 
I want to grab the `IPs` and ports from this html content:
(I've got this content as a String)

Ive read about `beautiful soup` and `regexp` - ive tried both but i cant get a solution - and `beautiful soup` is very slow.
sry for my bad english.

```
<tr class="proxyListOdd">
<td><a href="http://whois.sc/81.196.122.86" target="_blank">81.196.122.86</a></td>
<td>8080</td>
<td>Nein</td>
<td>3</td>
<td class="proxyList_Ping" >0.44 Sek.</td>
<td><img height="24px" width="24px" alt="Rumänien" title="Rumänien" src="http://static2.proxy-listen.de/0_proxy/images/flags/ro.png"></td>
<td class="proxyList_Online arrowUp">97% </td>
<td>22:06</td>
<td><input style="align: center" title="Proxyserver übernehmen" type="image" src="/0_proxy/images/ProxyswitcherButtonOn.png" onclick="de.proxy_listen.setProxy({'U2a66iQA': '70ODEuMTk2LjEyMi44Ng==', 'uhSRlFfS': '96ODA4MA==', 'h0zMxtxH':'21MQ=='}, 'https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/proxy-listen-de_proxyswitcher/');"></td>
<td><a href='proxy:name=Proxy-listen.de&host=81.196.122.86&port=8080&foxyProxyMode=this&confirmation=popup' title="Proxyserver in FoxyProxy übernehmen."><img height="24px" width="22px" alt="FoxyProxy" src="http://static.proxy-listen.de/0_proxy/images/foxyproxy.png"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="proxyListEven">
<td><a href="http://whois.sc/94.126.17.68" target="_blank">94.126.17.68</a></td>
<td>3128</td>
<td>Nein</td>
<td>3</td>
<td class="proxyList_Ping" >0.95 Sek.</td>
<td><img height="24px" width="24px" alt="Schweiz" title="Schweiz" src="http://static2.proxy-listen.de/0_proxy/images/flags/ch.png"></td>
<td class="proxyList_Online arrowUp">86% </td>
<td>22:06</td>
<td><input style="align: center" title="Proxyserver übernehmen" type="image" src="/0_proxy/images/ProxyswitcherButtonOn.png" onclick="de.proxy_listen.setProxy({'U2a66iQA': '65OTQuMTI2LjE3LjY4', 'uhSRlFfS': '78MzEyOA==', 'h0zMxtxH':'52MQ=='}, 'https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/proxy-listen-de_proxyswitcher/');"></td>
<td><a href='proxy:name=Proxy-listen.de&host=94.126.17.68&port=3128&foxyProxyMode=this&confirmation=popup' title="Proxyserver in FoxyProxy übernehmen."><img height="24px" width="22px" alt="FoxyProxy" src="http://static.proxy-listen.de/0_proxy/images/foxyproxy.png"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="proxyListOdd">
<td><a href="http://whois.sc/89.105.247.13" target="_blank">89.105.247.13</a></td>
<td>3128</td>
<td>Nein</td>
```

hope you can help me ;)
mfg henry

Comment: do you have a version that is valid html or xml?

Comment: The `&`'s in the html should be escaped to `&amp;` b.t.w. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> set(m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}', s))
{'81.196.122.86', '94.126.17.68', '89.105.247.13'}
```

Note that this regular expression is simplified, and doesn't actually capture all IP addresses (and captures some values that are not). If you want a more precise match, according to [inet_addr(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr) and [RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291), the whole regular expression looks like:

```
# IPv4, common format
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9])|
# IPv4, dotted hexadecimal
(?:0x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\.){3}0x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|
# IPv4, dotted octal
0[0-7]{3}\.){3}0[0-7]{3}|
# IPv4, one number, hexadecimal
0x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})|
# IPv4, one number, octal
0[0-7]{1,11})|
# IPv4, one number, hexadecimal
[1-4][0-9]{9}|0|[1-9][0-9]{0,7}|
# IPv6, preferred form (RFC 4291 2.2.1)
(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|
# IPv6, compressed syntax (RFC 4291 2.2.2)
(?:
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}::(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){,6}|
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1}::(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){,4}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}|
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){2}::(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){,3}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}|
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){3}::(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){,2}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}|
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){4}::(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}|
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){5}::[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}
)|
# IPv6, alternative form (RFC 4291 2.2.3, uncompressed)
(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){6}|(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]))|
# IPv6, alternative form (RFC 4291 2.2.3, compressed)
(?:
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}::(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){,4}|
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1}::(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){,3}|
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){2}::(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){,2}|
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){3}::(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){,1}|
  [0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){4}::
)
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]))
```

As you can see, if you really want to match all IP addresses, you should search for the approximate format, and then (if necessary) validate the addresses, for example with [`ipaddress`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress.html#module-ipaddress). Note that the above regular expression is *incomplete* for your case as it does not cover possible HTML character encodings such as `&#x31;` for 1.

Answer (score 1):

this works only with `IPv4`:

```
re.findall('(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)&port=(\d+)',s)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289901/how-to-search-for-ips-in-files-using-python/11289931#11289931)

EDIT: For this particular case, you would have to do something different and regex out the data from this particular set of HTML data (as IP's appear multiple times):

```
print [ ":".join((y,z)) for x,y,z in re.findall('proxyList((?=Even)|(?=Odd)).*?_blank">(.*?)</a></td>.*?<td>([0-9]+)</td>',data,flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)]
```

You could have also regex'ed on the 'proxy:name=Proxy-listen' Part, which Marco de Wit does.

Otherwise:

```
re.findall('(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)',data)
```

which finds all `IPv4` addresses, to add ports onto that, modify it to be:

```
re.findall('((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)):([0-9]{1,5})*',data)
```

Which should find all IP's and ports in this format: `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYYY`
(That stated, it doesn't check if the ports are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#module-xml.dom.minidom)? From the documentation:

xml.dom.minidom is a light-weight implementation of the Document Object Model interface. It is intended to be simpler than the full DOM and also significantly smaller.