# How can I find if a text has an IP address using regex?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regexp to check if an IP is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011855/regexp-to-check-if-an-ip-is-valid)

I'm not good with regex and I searched for this but all I can find is matching IP addresses that have white space before and after the numbers for example it matches this only:

```
Text before 192.168.1.1 Text after
```

How can I make it match any ip address, I don't want the IP I just want to know if a text has an IP, for example I want this to match too:

```
text before192.168.1.1text after
```

I tried these ones:

```
\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b

^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

and thanks in advance.

Comment: why not show us that regexp that *almost* does what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address

Comment: remove the `\b` from the beginning and end.  In the second case, remove the `^` from the beginning, and remove the `$` from the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $string, $match)) {
    if (filter_var($match[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        // we have an IP
    }
}
```

Yes, you could construct a regex which would match 0-255 directly and all the other rules an IP must follow, but this is so much more straight forward.