# Returning the country code of an IP address

Tags: python, csv, python-3.4

I have a CSV file, where IP ranges are stored along with their landcode:

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","16779264","16781311","CN","China"
```

This can be read like this:

```
range_start, range_stop, ignored, ignored, country_code, country_name
```

When the user asks for a particular IP address, I want to return him the country code corresponding to this IP. Here for example, `1.0.9.10` would return `CN` for China, because it is between `1.0.8.0` and `1.0.15.255.`

I don't know how to deal with that. Here is what I've done so far, but I doubt I'm in the right direction:

```
import csv

with open("GeoIPCountryWhois.csv") as csvfile:

readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")

IP_LOWs = []
IP_HIGHs = []
Land_CODEs = []
Lands = []

for row in readCSV:
    IP_LOW = row[0]
    IP_HIGH = row[1]
    Land_CODE = row[4]
    Land = row[5]

    IP_LOWs.append(IP_LOW)
    IP_HIGHs.append(IP_HIGH)
    Land_CODEs.append(Land_CODE)
    Lands.append(Land)

whatIP = input("What IP should be looked up? ")

codedex = IP_LOWs.index(whatIP)
landdex = Lands.index(whatIP)
IP_to_Code = Land_CODE[codedex]
IP_to_land = Land[landdex]

print(IP_to_Code)
print(IP_to_land)
```

Comment: Add an indentation block after `with open("GeoIPCountryWhois.csv") as csvfile` :)

Comment: Why are you ignoring columns 3 and 4? Those are the numeric equivalents of the start and end IP. You should convert the input IP to a number, and compare them to those ranges. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590965/convert-an-ip-string-to-a-number-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the library [netaddr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr) while dealing with IP Addresses.

```
from netaddr import *
IPAddress("1.0.3.255")>IPAddress("1.1.2.1")
#False
```

Then you can use something like:

**Note:** The below code is untested, since I don't have your data. You might have to make minor changes to actually run the code. If you get any error while running this, post it here, I will try to rectify.

```
import csv
from netaddr import *
with open("GeoIPCountryWhois.csv") as csvfile:

    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")

    whatIP = input("What IP should be looked up? ")

    for row in readCSV:
        IP_LOW = IPAddress(row[0])    
        IP_HIGH = IPAddress(row[1])
        Land = row[4]

        if IPAddress(whatIP)>=IP_LOW and IPAddress(whatIP)<=IP_HIGH:
            print Land
```

Comment: It some have comes with an error saying:
"netaddr.core.AddrFormatError: failed to detect a valid IP address from '.0.0.'"

Answer (score 1):

Using the code from [Convert an IP string to a number and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590965/convert-an-ip-string-to-a-number-and-vice-versa), you can convert the input IP to a number. Then you can compare it to the numeric version of the start/end IP, which are in columns 3 and 4 of the CSV.

```
import csv

with open("GeoIPCountryWhois.csv") as csvfile:

    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")

    GeoIPs = []

    for row in readCSV:
        GeoIPs.append({ low: row[2], high: row[3], land_code: row[4], land: row[5] })

    whatIP = input("What IP should be looked up? ")
    whatIP_long = ip2long(whatIP)        
    found_range = next((GeoIP for GeoIP in GeoIPs if GeoIP.low <= whatIP_long <= GeoIP.high), None)
    if found_range:
        IP_to_Code = found_range.land_code
        IP_to_land = found_range.land

    print(IP_to_Code)
    print(IP_to_land)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit unrelated to the question, but reinventing the wheel made me throw my two cents. If it's not homework or a learning project, you can use GeoIP + free MaxMind database (or the paid version). The code is stable, tested and ready to use in production.

**Example:**

```
#
from pygeoip import GeoIP, MEMORY_CACHE
#
try:
    import win_inet_pton#patches socket library for Windows use
except ImportError:
    pass
import socket

###############################################################################

def is_valid_ipv4(ip_str):
    """
    Check the validity of an IPv4 address
    """
    try:
        socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, ip_str)#@UndefinedVariable
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            socket.inet_aton(ip_str)
        except socket.error:
            return False
        return ip_str.count('.') == 3
    except socket.error:
        return False
    return True

def is_valid_ipv6(ip_str):
    """
    Check the validity of an IPv6 address
    """
    try:
        socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip_str)#@UndefinedVariable
    except socket.error:
        return False
    return True

###############################################################################

def get_country_from_ip(ip):

    geo_record = None

    if is_valid_ipv4(ip):
        geo_country_ipv4_db = GeoIP('[path/to/dat/file]GeoLiteCity.dat', MEMORY_CACHE)
        geo_record = geo_country_ipv4_db.record_by_addr(ip)

    if is_valid_ipv6(ip):
        geo_country_ipv6_db = GeoIP('[path/to/dat/file]GeoLiteCityv6.dat', MEMORY_CACHE)
        geo_record = geo_country_ipv6_db.record_by_addr(ip)

    if geo_record:
        return geo_record.get('country_code', '').lower()

    return None

###############################################################################

print get_country_from_ip('1.0.9.10')
```

**Requirements:**

- GeoIp: https://github.com/appliedsec/pygeoip
- MaxMind free databases: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/
- For windows only: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_inet_pton

**Related:**

[Regexp to check if an IP is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011855/regexp-to-check-if-an-ip-is-valid/23502065#23502065)

Install the required extensions, replace the "[path/to/dat/file]" and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working only with IPV4 addresses, convert from dotted-decimal notation into its 32-bit equivalent. Now it is a matter of looking up the location using the 32-bit IP addresses provided in the source file in columns 3 and 4.

If you will be performing multiple lookups, a good data structure to use is a sorted list. Lookup can be performed using the bisection algorithm provided in the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) module.

Note that there are gaps in the source data [GeoIPCountryWhois.csv](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoIPCountryCSV.zip) for unallocated IP addresses, or those IPs in a private address range, so a little upfront data massaging is required. Here is a class that loads the data from the file, fills in any gaps, and uses `bisect_left()` to perform lookups:

```
import csv
import socket
import struct

from bisect import bisect_left

def ip2long(ip):
    """
    Convert an IP string to long (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9591005/21945)
    """
    packedIP = socket.inet_aton(ip)
    return struct.unpack("!L", packedIP)[0]


class GeoIPCountry(object):
    def __init__(self, geoips_file):
        """
        Load IP range location map from CSV file filling in any empty ranges as
        we go. Assumes that the data in geoips_file is sorted by IP address.
        """
        r = csv.reader(geoips_file)
        self.geoips = []
        last_hi = 0
        for row in r:
            if int(row[2]) != last_hi+1:
                self.geoips.append((last_hi+1, int(row[2])-1, None, None))
            self.geoips.append((int(row[2]), int(row[3]), row[4], row[5]))
            last_hi = int(row[3])
        if last_hi < ip2long('255.255.255.255'):
            self.geoips.append((last_hi+1, ip2long('255.255.255.255'), None, None))
        self.keys = [geoip[1] for geoip in self.geoips]
#        assert sorted(self.keys) == self.keys

    def lookup_country(self, ip_address):
        """
        Return tuple of country code and country name for an IP address.
        """
        return self.geoips[bisect_left(self.keys, ip2long(ip_address))][-2:]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('GeoIPCountryWhois.csv') as geoips_file:
        geoip = GeoIPCountry(geoips_file)

    for ip_address in ('0.1.2.3', '1.2.3.4', '192.168.1.1', '203.123.4.23',
                       '123.132.123.123', '223.255.255.255', '255.255.255.255'):
        country = geoip.lookup_country(ip_address)
        if country[0] is not None:
            print "{:<15} -> {} ({})".format(ip_address, country[1], country[0])
        else:
            print "{:<15} -> unknown".format(ip_address)
```

**Output**

```
0.1.2.3         -> unknown
1.2.3.4         -> United States (US)
192.168.1.1     -> unknown
203.123.4.23    -> Singapore (SG)
123.132.123.123 -> China (CN)
223.255.255.255 -> Australia (AU)
255.255.255.255 -> unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IP Find for this.

```
import urllib, json
url = 'https://ipfind.co/?auth=ip=' + ip_address;
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

This will return a JSON object with ISO country code as a property.